# C# Taking the "IndexOf" a string and only the first character of the string is being shown as having a position

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a coding problem for a class and have been stuck for about 2 hours trying to get past this part. I need a nudge in the right direction. We are making a typing of the dead like game in a console application in Visual Studio. Right now I am trying to get the characters the user inputs to show up as being correct when matched against the characters in the displayed phrase.

```
    // attributes
    string zombie;
    string phrase;
    int length;
    public void PlayingGame()
    {
        while (playerhealth > 0)
            {
                if (zombie == null)
                {
                    //load random zombie and phrasse
                    zombie = data.RandomZombie();
                    phrase = data.RandomPhrase();
                    //reset index and timer
                    zombieTimer = 0;
                    letterIndex = 0;
                    //displays zombie and phrase
                    Console.WriteLine(zombie);
                    Console.WriteLine(phrase);
                    length = phrase.Length;
                    // given loop info
                    while (Console.KeyAvailable==false) 
                    {
                        //reads characters entered
                        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                        string letter = key.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();

                        // checks to see if the letter position from the   Indexof is equal to the position in the phrase
                        if (phrase.IndexOf(letter) == letterIndex)
                        {   
                            // displays! if correct                             
                            Console.Write("!");
                            // moves to the next letter
                            letterIndex++;
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            // displays :( if wrong
                            Console.Write(":( restart phrase ");
                            //resets the Index to start phrase over
                            letterIndex = 0;
                        }


                    }
```

I have done some testing with it and when I run the program my zombie comes up the phrase is displayed and I can type the first character in the phrase and it will be displayed as being correct. Indicated with a "!". However after thee first character when I try to take the Index it says it is = to -1. However if the second character is a space(" ") it will see that as correct. Also one of my phrases has numbers in it and the IndexOf found the position of the numbers.

my test class is:

```
ZombieData zombies = new ZombieData();
        zombies.LoadZombies();
        zombies.LoadPhrases("phrases.txt");
        Game game = new Game();
        game.PlayingGame();
```

I also have a class with methods that get the data for the zombies and phrases from files and then return a random zombie and phrase for use in the game.

Comment: it suggested it I didn't really know what it was

Answer (score 1):

Alright sorry sometimes just writing it out helps to see the problem. I changed the code a little bit and realized what my problem was. Thanks for listening.

```
 public void PlayingGame()
    {
        while (playerhealth > 0)
            {
                if (zombie == null)
                {
                    //load random zombie and phrasse
                    zombie = data.RandomZombie();
                    phrase = data.RandomPhrase();
                    //reset index and timer
                    zombieTimer = 0;
                    letterIndex = 0;
                    //displays zombie and phrase
                    Console.WriteLine(zombie);
                    Console.WriteLine(phrase);
                    length = phrase.Length;
                    // given loop info
                    while (Console.KeyAvailable==false) 
                    {
                        //reads characters entered
                        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                        string letter = key.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();

                        // checks to see if the letter position from the Indexof is equal to the position in the phrase
                        // changed this to directly compare the letters instead of seeing if it was in the right porition and realized the problem was that I didn't realize the loop my instructor gave me was using ToUpper and making all the characters uppercase
                        if (letter == phrase[letterIndex].ToString().ToUpper())
                        {   

                            // displays! if correct                             
                            Console.Write("!");
                            // moves to the next letter
                            letterIndex++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(letter);
                            Console.WriteLine(phrase[letterIndex].ToString());
                            // displays :( if wrong
                            Console.Write(":( restart phrase ");
                            //resets the Index to start phrase over
                            letterIndex = 0;
                        }


                    }



                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

My instructor provided the Console.KeyAvailable while loop and the string letter and i didn't realize the problem was all of the characters needed to be capitolized.